# Unity How to get get a characters width properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am attempting to create a script that when a line of text would be approaching the width of the line it would attempt to wrap the text properly (ie. if the character is not '-' or ' ' then add a hyphen between letters of a word (like how word editing software does it) but when I attempt to run it a bunch of my characters disappear.

This is the text that I am testing with, "An Aberration has a bizarre anatomy, strange abilities, an alien mindset, or any combination of the three."

but these are the results of my test script

"Found with info (' ','e','r','a','t','i','o','h','s','l','d')"
"Found without info ('A','n','b','z','m','y',',','g','c','f','.')"
"Didnt Find ()"

and the output from compiling the text using only the characters that have available info is " erratio has a iarre aato strae ailities a alie idset or a oiatio o the three"

and here is my testing script

```cs
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] 
    private Type m_Type; 
    // Not System.Type, is a custom class

    [SerializeField] 
    private Font m_Font; 
    // Set to Arial for testing.

    private List<string> m_FoundWithInfo;
    private List<string> m_FoundWithoutInfo;
    private List<string> m_DidntFind;
    private void Awake()
    {
        m_FoundWithInfo = new List<string>();
        m_FoundWithoutInfo = new List<string>();
        m_DidntFind = new List<string>();
        foreach (char c in m_Type.GetDescription())
        {
            if (m_Font.HasCharacter(c))
            {
                if (m_Font.GetCharacterInfo(c, 
                    out CharacterInfo info, 14, FontStyle.Normal))
                {
                    if (!m_FoundWithInfo.Contains($"'{c}'"))
                    {
                        m_FoundWithInfo.Add($"'{c}'");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!m_FoundWithoutInfo.Contains($"'{c}'"))
                    {
                        m_FoundWithoutInfo.Add($"'{c}'");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!m_DidntFind.Contains($"'{c}'"))
                {
                    m_DidntFind.Add($"'{c}'");
                }
            }
        }
        Debug.Log($"Found with info ({string.Join(",", m_FoundWithInfo)})");
        Debug.Log($"Found without info ({string.Join(",", m_FoundWithoutInfo)})");
        Debug.Log($"Didnt Find ({string.Join(",", m_DidntFind)})");
    }
}
```

How can I make this work so that the returned text is otherwise identical to the original?

To clarify the Test script only checks to see what necessary characters don't have any CharacterInfo associated with them.

Comment: I don't really understand how your lists are supposed to work together ... you ignore duplicate entries that's why some characters "disappear" ... let's take `An Aberration has a` you start with the `An` the second `A` is already skipped since it is already found before .. the next thing is the `b` .. then you skip all items found with info etc .. Now what I don't get is: in the end when printing you seem to simply ignore all characters that are contained in the `FoundWithoutInfo` ... don't you rather want to sum up the width of **all** characters and insert a line break after a certain limit?

Comment: `like how word editing software does it` .. note that they mostly use a certain dictionary or word separation rules ..

Comment: You have if conditions that don't have else condition. You are missing some characters here

Comment: @A.Gerber well you probably mean the `if (!m_FoundWithoutInfo.Contains($"'{c}'"))                    { m_FoundWithoutInfo.Add($"'{c}'"); }` etc. ... that seems to be intended though ... it makes sue each character is added to the list only once ..

Comment: @derHugo Your last 2 points are true, however since the panel may be of virtually any size and font size, style and the actual font itself may present different character widths, I need to know the width of each character. the problem is that I can't get the widths of all needed characters. Your first point however isn't quite accurate, this script isn't designed to actually calculate the widths yet, just to find out what characters seem to be missing, its simply to test any given font against an arbitrary string.

Comment: From [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/wrap-character-instead-of-word.735698/): `The easiest way to achieve that is to use Soft Hyphenation and to inject similar to how it is done in the TMP Examples & Extras example scene called Soft Hyphenation.` They insert a special character `\u00AD` anywhere where a word **could** be hyphenated .. then they parse through the text I guess probably quite similar how you are trying. Maybe you can use something similar or at least checkout how they did it ;)

Comment: @derHugo I will definitely check that out, but what I am trying to do is to split a word regardless of whether or not it "can" be hyphenated so that I don't end up with lines of text with for example 3 words on it because word 4 happens to be too long to fit on the line, and thus also end up with a line that only has that word on it, if that makes sense

Comment: @RWolfe the se thing can happen with your approach though ;) Just that you would allow word splitting like `This is a quite unor-thodox way to split word-s` .. you know what I mean? ;)

Comment: @derHugo it would certainly seem weird, the idea is that if the line reaches a certain length (width - (2 * hyphenwidth)) then we add a hyphen and a new line, so that the text more or less fills the text box end to end like so `"An Aberration has\n a bizarre anatomy,\n strange abilities,\n an alien min-\ndset, or any combin-\nation of the three."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Getting character info

Unity font management operates on textures to render characters, and needs to be informed what characters to load in order to add them to a font texture, before you can use them while rendering text. Unless you request loading characters outside your example, having characters that exist in a font but don't have info available are due to not having them loaded into a font texture when you query font for their info.

`Font.HasCharacter` checks if a font you use has character defined - if it returns false, that character doesn't exist in a font and can't be loaded to be used. Example would be checking a non-latin symbol in font that covers only latin characters. `Font.HasCharacter` returning true means you can load that character to a font texture.

`Font.GetCharacterInfo` get information about a symbol from currently loaded font texture - so there is a possibility that loaded font may have a character available, but not loaded; this will cause `Font.GetCharacterInfo` to return false and make character not render if your render text manually. To work around that, you need to request Unity to load characters you will need by using [RequestCharactersInTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Font.RequestCharactersInTexture.html) - documentation also contains an example on how to handle manual text rendering including font texture updates. Until you have a character loaded, you won't be able to get its font info, since it doesn't exist in currently used Font texture. When calling `RequestCharactersInTexture`, pass all characters that occur in your text regardless if they're loaded or not - that way you make sure Font won't unload a character that was previously loaded when loading new ones.

## Determining line breaks

When working on a solution to determine where to put line breaks, you may need to take [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) into account - depending on surrounding characters, font may want to use different distance between characters or sometimes even use different glyphs. If you render text manually, make sure to have consistent handling of kerning between calculating linebreaks - no kerning is a good strategy, as long as font you're using doesn't depend heavily on kerning. If you want to support kerning, you should work on substrings instead of single characters and try to find best points of introducing line break for a whole line - width of a line may be different from sum of all character widths that occur in said line.

Comment: Awesome this is exactly the information I was looking for, I will try it soon, and see if it does what I actually need it to do, but based on the additional information you provided I can only assume that it will.

Comment: This all fits the API - but doesn't seem to fit reality (any more). Unity's own docs are fake - the Editor simply doesn't adhere to their own rules. Unity's internal APIs are able to return values for text-size *without* waiting for a callback, and Unity's own callbacks ... no longer execute in the Editor. Have you got  RequestCharactersInTexture working in current Unity (2020)?